# Converting parent / children structure to object

Tags: javascript

I need to convert js object like this:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "A",
    "parent": null,
    "children": [
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "B",
            "parent": 1,
            "children": []
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "C",
            "parent": 1,
            "children": [
                {
                    "id": 4,
                    "name": "D",
                    "parent": 3,
                    "children": []
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

to another like this:

```
{
    "А": [
        {
            "B": "value",
            "C": [
                {
                    "D": "value"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I wrote the function, but it returns the wrong object with several nested arrays:

```
const convert = (obj) => {
    return obj.map((i) => {
        return Object.keys(i).filter(y => y === 'name').map(key => {
            return i['children'].length > 0 ? { [i[key]]: convert(i['children']) } : { [i[key]]: 'value' }
        });
    })
};
```

How to change my implementation for getting the right object?

Comment: I don't quite understand the desired output logic. Under what circumstances should a child be grouped with other children in the same output object, and when should it be a separate item in an array? Eg why not `"A": [ { "B": "value" }, { "C": [` - or, always as an object instead of arrays, `"A": { "B": "value", "C": {`?

Comment: I don't understand it either. Where does "value" come from?

Comment: @0xc14m1z `'value'` is just hard-coded in when there are no children for a given object, I think.

Comment: I think that too, but maybe there's something more :)

Comment: Very similar to this deleted question earlier today: [Converting tree to object with random values](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66650408/4642212), but at least this one includes a coding attempt. Is this homework, or is this your [second account](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/57682/289905)?

Comment: @0xc14m1z yes, 'value' is hard-coded

Comment: @SebastianSimon, yes it's js course task )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could build the entries from objects and map nested children, if exists.

```js
const
    transform = array => Object.fromEntries(array.map(({ name, children }) =>
        [name, children.length ? [transform(children)] : 'value']
    )),
    data = { id: 1, name: "A", parent: null, children: [{ id: 2, name: "B", parent: 1, children: [] }, { id: 3, name: "C", parent: 1, children: [{ id: 4, name: "D", parent: 3, children: [] }] }] },
    result = transform([data]);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!